# Why does the maximum modulus principle hold intuitively?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm struggling to understand why the maximum modulus principle holds. Why is it that a holomorphic function that is nonconstant in an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ cannot have a local maximum inside the subset? Intuitively, why are no such curves with local maxima not holomorphic?

More specifically, I've been trying to figure out why a holomorphic function on compact complex connected curve must be constant. This directly follows from the maximum modulus principle because there must be a maximum due to compactness, but I don't understand why either of these properties hold.

Comment: It is a consequence of the “open mapping theorem” (which you might find more intuitive or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic, it's real and imaginary part are harmonic, i.e. they satisfy Laplace's equation. This is the equation satisfied by a stretched membranes. Such a physical configuration intuitively cannot have bumps. That is a cool way to see it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Laplace's equation. Can you clarify what you mean by stretched membranes?

Comment: if $u=Re f$, then $\nabla^2 u=0$ (Laplace's equation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation). This is nothing more than a rewriting of Cauchy-Riemann conditions. And it is the equation that an actual physical membrane follows. For instance consider a drum, by membrane I mean thin layer of material you hit to produce sound. if you imagine for instance chopping off a bit of the side of the drum, the resting form of the membrane will be the solution of Laplace's equation.

Comment: I realized I could also mention that for this functions, the value they take is the average of points around it, so that's another intuitive argument for the maximum modulus principle.

I guess this is discussed also in whatever book you are using, but if you are looking for references, Chapter 10 of Ulrich's in complex analysis should be a good place to look